# Rails 4: DOM is ready and AJAX response leads to duplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

**Question**

Is there a good technique to avoid calling the same code  javascript(jquery) in AJAX responses?

**Example**

Lets say I have these views and js files

index.html.erb

```
<div class="listing_users">
  <%= render @users %>
</div>
```

_user.html.erb

```
<div class="user">
    <%= @user.name %>
</div>
```

users.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".user").css({"background-color": "red"})
})
```

When I create a new user through AJAX I make rails render this in my `create.js.erb` response.

```
$(".listing_users").append("<%= j(render(:partial => @users)) %>")
$(".listing_users").css({"background-color": "red"})
```

**The** `$(".listing_users").css({"background-color": "red"})` **line needs to be there for the newly rendered partial.**

**Possible solution**

I am aware that I just can make a function like this

```
function set_red(){
  $(".user").css({"background-color": "red"})
}
```

and just call it both in when the DOM is ready and in the AJAX response. But, this also calls the code two times.

Answer (score 1):

You can share a [jquery 'deferred' object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) between the ready handler and the ajax callback.

The `done` method of this object would contain your code, while you call its resolve method from within the ajax callback and the ready handler.

The resolution takes place only once, even if requested multiple times.

code sample:

```
// jquery must have been included here
var g_cbguard = new Deferred();
g_cbguard
    .done(function () {
        // your code that shall be executed only once
    })
;
// ...

// ready handler
$(document).ready(function () {
    // ...
    g_cbguard.resolve();
    // ...
});
// ...

// somewhere else in your ajax call
$.ajax(
    //...)
).done( function () {
    g_cbguard.resolve();
});
// ...
```

Comment: Great answer. I didn't know about the `jquery 'deferred' object`. It does not work in the way I use AJAX with rails, but I am looking into how to use it with rails